# How to populate an array from each character in an element from another array?

Tags: java, arrays

Essentially I have an array named symbols `String[] symbols = {"a*", "j^", "y!"}`
which from that I would like to create another array with each of the single characters from the symbols array being in a single element in the new array, something like this `char[] newArr = {'a', '*' ..... }`.

In terms me solving this my guess would be to iterate over the elements in the first array then in a nested loop loop over the single characters in that element then assign it to the new array there, but I am unsure how to do that.

Comment: Iterate the `symbols`. With each entry, iterate over each `char` and add that `char` to the `newArr` array

Comment: Do you need the result as `String[]`? It seems to me that a `char[]` would be more useful here.

Comment: oh yes sorry missed that will edit

Comment: So is the input a `char[]` as well?

Comment: Input can't be a `char[]` as it has two characters together

Comment: @GeorgeSmith That's illegal code. Input should be `String[]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you start by making a single `String` from your `String[] symbols`. You might use a [`for-each` loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) and a [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) and something like

```
    String[] symbols = { "a*", "j^", "y!" };
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (String symbol : symbols) {
        sb.append(symbol);
    }
```

Then you can use [`String.toCharArray()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray%28%29) to convert that into a `char[]`

```
    char[] chars = sb.toString().toCharArray();
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(chars));
```

Output is

```
[a, *, j, ^, y, !]
```

Answer (score 1):

I won't give you a full solution, but I'll guide you so you have something to begin with.

Iterate on `symbols` array, it contains String. You can construct a new `char` array using [`String#toCharArray`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray--), then you'll have each `char` from each String that you can easily create a String from it and insert it to the new array.

Comment: He changed the question... it's a `char[]` for the result, not a `String[]`

Comment: @Ascalonian This doesn't change anything... OP can simply not convert the char to String. I just want to guide him..

Answer (score 1):

This might solve your problem:

```
int length = 0;
for(final String s : symbol) { //first get the length of the new array
    length += s.length;
}
char[] result = new char[length];
int pos = 0;
for(final String s : symbol) {  //then fill the new array with data
    System.arraycopy(s.toCharArray(), 0, result, pos, s.length());
    pos += s.length();
}
```

So first of all, it counts how long the result will be by just summing up the lengths of all inputs. This is necessary in order to initialize the `char[]` with a given length.

Now we already have our empty result array with the right size and can simply fill it with our input.
We do this by iterating through every input string and copying its `.getCharArray()` into the result array at the current position. After each input symbol copied into our result, we increase `pos` so that the next entry will be copied into the right position.

JavaDoc of [System.arraycopy(src, srcPos, dest, destPos, length)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy(java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int))

This also uses no unnecessary Collection API classes and works fine with Java primitives :)

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Just edited it. I just declare most local fields as `final` because it prevents one from accidentally changing it. It's just a habit.

Comment: Two passes, but it is very nice.